# Склонение словосочетания "муниципальное образование Суворовский сельсовет"

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно написать в официальном документе: "Генплан хутора Сухоозерного муниципального образования *Суворовский сельсовет* Предгорного района Ставропольского края" или "Генплан хутора Сухоозерного муниципального образования *Суворовского сельсовета* Предгорного района Ставропольского края"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правилен первый вариант. При этом название муниципального образования надо взять в кавычки

Comment: Виктор, не надо таких скоропалительных рекомендаций. 
Семь раз подумайте.
Человеку же для дела.

А если это безымянный хутор, и "Сухозерное муниципальное образование" некоего "Суворовского сельсовета..."? Такой вариант лично мне представляется даже более логичным.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в современном канцелярском языке после аббревиатуры МО идет в кавычках название этого муниципального образования.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Уважаемая Марта! Если Вы согласны с моим ответом, отметьте его, кликнув на символическую руку с поднятым большим пальцем слева от моего ответа

Comment: Не получается, к сожалению. :(
При нажатии выскакивает окошко со словами:"Недостаточно очков...
Минимальная требуемая репутация - 15 (у вас 3)".

Comment: Это потому, что Вы сначала нажимали "руку" с опущенным большим пальцем, а я просил - с поднятым пальцем

Comment: Виктор, а вы сначала проголосуйте за вопрос)))
Если вам так эти очки дороги.

Comment: О, получилось! =0)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то надо прежде всего смотреть образующие документы.
С точки зрения логики тут что-то явно перепутано или пропущено.

~~~~~

А, вон оно что...  Действительно пропущены слова "сельское поселение".

Сухоозёрный — хутор[2] в составе муниципального образования «Сельское поселение Суворовский сельсовет» Предгорного района Ставропольского края
(Вики)

Если это соответствует истине, то в Генплане, хоть застрелись, опускать эту часть нельзя.

Правильно:

***"Генплан хутора Сухоозёрного муниципального образования «Сельское поселение Суворовский сельсовет» Предгорного района Ставропольского края".***
Повторюсь, если процитированное полное название хутора соответствует истине, то только так и никак иначе. Желательно даже точки над Ё не терять в "Сухоозёрный". 
Если же что-то там по-другому, то напишите, как оно на самом деле, ибо возможны варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть слово "хутор", то название его должно быть в им. падеже. Тем более, это фраза для документа. Поэтому "хутора Сухоозёрный".

Comment: Не вполне понятно, почему название хутора, тем более такого склоняемого, должно стоять в им.падеже. Мы по этому поводу недавно дискутировали.  Можно допустить им.п. применительно к именам собственным, выраженным словами среднего рода, например "хутора Солнцево", но не мужского рода

Comment: Виктор, я понимаю, что вам процесс интересен, но этот мосент регулируется совершенно другими правилами.

@Инна:
Правило таково: географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, _**хутор**_, река, выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование. Правильно: в городе Москве, в г. Санкт-Петербурге, в городе Владивостоке.
(Курсив мой, B-s) 
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/hot10/